# Magento2 Custom Template KnockoutJS

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs

I have set up a custom template and all working fine apart from KO templating is not working in the custom theme so things lick the checkoutpage is not rendering.

I have the following set:
- One page checkout
- User does not have to be registered
- parent theme Magento/blank

However, things that use the KO rendering template (like estimated shipping and checkout).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was a conflict in my themes requiref-config.js file. If i removed this file al together, it relies on the parent theme and therefore works again